# Registration Module in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, registration, dotnetnuke-7

I am trying to secure my DNN site running on DNN version 7.01.02

WHat i am looking for is that anybody who registers for a new account must enter a valid email id and should be able to login only after he clicks the verification mail.

Currently the way i have it is Once the user enters his Email and chooses a password he is directly logged into the site and only gets the following message.

[image]

[image]

Here are the site settings for the Website i use to control the user Registration.
So how can i change this config so that the user can only log into the portal once he goes through the verification mail

**PS**: My verification mail works. I have checked the SMTP settings.

Answer (score 1):

As an administrator, go to Site Settings, User Account Settings and change the User Registration Setting to "Verified."

The user will be required to enter a verification code when they log in for the first time.

Comment: Thats what i did. Does not work... user gets logged in the first time before he verifies his mail...

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the private setting, but I have a low traffic site. IF you dont mind verifying the accounts you can do that. Also you can set it to redirect to a page where it tells them that the account needs to be approved before they can login